# How do you make Node.js talk to a SOAP service?

Tags: javascript, soap, node.js, soap-client

I can't seem to find any examples on this. I see a listing on github for Node that says "Newspaper Club – Uses node.js for wrapping a nasty SOAP interface to InDesign Server.", but I don't see any code.

Thank you.

EDIT: I'm guessing that I could just find any javascript/SOAP kit and port it to Node. Any suggestions on a good one?

Comment: Bump This might be of interest :) http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/wcf-and-nodejs-better-together

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found what looks like a decent SOAP client for Node.js [on github](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap)

Comment: Link only. Please add an example on how to consume a soap api.

Answer (score -3):

After spending some time researching this, the consensus seems to be that you don't want to do SOAP with Node.js. What you want to do is make Node.js listen for events and make your non-Node services push data at Node using Http.

UPDATE: I was pointing out what the consensus of the Node community at the time. That was not an opinion that I shared, but that was the most common response that I got and there was no stable SOAP client at the time. I have now remarked the answer. Thank You.

Comment: Question: but if you still want to use SOAP to talk to other services?

Comment: No, actually I do want to do SOAP with Node.js. I want to consume a SOAP web service with Node.js. Why shouldn't I want to do this?

Comment: I agree with Tim - Node should have a SOAP Client so it can interact with external SOAP-based services. This requires writing/porting a SOAP-client that relies on async-requests so that Node makes the most of it.